# Angular cannot read property 'name/description' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am learning angular for about a week now. I have encountered this error `cannot read property of undefined`. I have attached two pictures below

1. Error Encounter
2. Folder structure

[image: Error Encountered]
[image]

I am wondering why I got 3 data looping when I only have 2. Here is the code in my `recipe-list.component.ts`

```
  recipes: Recipe[] = [
new Recipe('Test Recipe', 'Test Description', 'https://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/sites/teens/files/a_recipe_1.jpg'), new Recipe('Test Recipe', 'Test Description', 'https://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/sites/teens/files/a_recipe_1.jpg') ];
```

and I am looping the two data in my `recipe-list.component.html`

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <button class="btn btn-success">New Recipe</button>
</div></div><div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <app-recipe-item *ngFor="let i of recipes" [recipe]="i"></app-recipe-item>
</div>
```

and passing it to my recipe-item folder

```
export class RecipeItemComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() recipe: Recipe;}
```

and in my recipe HTML file this is how I coded it

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
<div class="float-left">
    <h4 class="list-group-item">
        {{recipe.name}}
    </h4>
    <p class="list-group-item">{{recipe.description}}</p>
</div>
<span class="float-right">
    <img src="{{recipe.imagePath}}" alt="{{recipe.name}}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 120px;">
</span>
```

Did I do wrong or wrong syntax in my code?.

Comment: Your Recipe object is an array. you must loop through before using interpolation

Comment: @SrikaraBS Do i need to loop it again even I already loop it onces? Here `<app-recipe-item *ngFor="let i of recipes" [recipe]="i"></app-recipe-item>`

Comment: Defensive programming. In the template, instead of `recipe.description`, for example, use `recipe?.description`. The '?' is called 'optional chaining' or 'elvis operator'  and will avoid everything breaking when `recipe`, for some reason, is null/undefined (which is the case when your component is created)

Comment: remove it from here. Pass the entire array to child component and loop it there

Comment: @julianobrasil I am guessing my problem is that it loop for the third time even I only have 2 array data. I don't know why.

Comment: @SrikaraBS sorry but this is how he structure the code. I am referring to the tutorial that I am watching now. I don't know why I have this error, but to him he didn't have even I am following hes code

Comment: @KiRa then maybe use defensive programming as suggested by julianobrasil. That is the best way to go

Comment: @SrikaraBS I tried it and it's working. But my problem now is why it loop 3 times even I only have two data in my array. Maybe that causes the error. You can see it in the first picture.

Comment: @KiRa, can you console it in app-item component after you take @input? that would say if there is an extra item

Comment: @SrikaraBS and julianobrasil solve :) spend a 30mins to locate the problem. BTW thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Solve**

There was a `<app-recipe-item></app-recipe-item>` called in my recipes.component. That's why I got an error of property of undefined because in that component.html I didn't pass any data.